# ASP.Net Web template missing on Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

First I had to uninstall both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 because of errors in the IDE and slow startup/compiling/etc., now that I installed everything back, Visual Studio 2015 does not show the ASP.Net Web Template by any chance.

I've tried installing extensions and tools suggested on StackOverflow and ASP.Net Forums but still can't work on ASP.Net MVC projects. I'm reinstalling the Web Developer Tools for the second time but still can't see the Web item the the project templates tree (New Project dialog).

What else can I do? It's been one week since I finally have been able to uninstall using TotalUninstaller from Microsoft and spent many hour installing VS 2015.

I have run every devenv command line switch (ResetSettings, installvstemplates, etc) and deleted the ComponentModelCache folder but it didn't make any difference.